# Intellij unable to open a project containing 4gb .git

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have a repository containing several sub-projects. The directory size is 4GB. The projects themselves are not very large but over time, the different commits and branches have led to a huge `.git`

```
$ du -hs myproject/
4.0G    myproject/

$ du -hs myproject/.git
3.8G    myproject/.git
```

In the past, I've used Intellij to `Open` this folder. I noticed a few days ago, when I try to Open nothing happens. I've tried re-installing Intellij, re-cloned the project, even increased Intellij's memory heap to 4GB..nothing helps. It opens only when I do shallow cloning with a dept of 1. Please is there anything else I can do?

Full log

```
2020-11-21 18:11:02,698 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2020-11-21 18:11:02,727 [     29]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IC-191.8026.42, 30 Jul 2019 07:04) 
2020-11-21 18:11:02,728 [     30]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Mac OS X (10.15.7, x86_64) 
2020-11-21 18:11:02,728 [     30]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2020-11-21 18:11:02,728 [     30]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.212-b4 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2020-11-21 18:11:02,734 [     36]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Xverify:none -XX:ErrorFile=/Users/mblaise/java_error_in_idea_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/Users/mblaise/java_error_in_idea.hprof -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2019.1 -Didea.executable=idea -Didea.platform.prefix=Idea -Didea.home.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents 
2020-11-21 18:11:02,734 [     36]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext: [sunec.jar, nashorn.jar, cldrdata.jar, jfxrt.jar, dnsns.jar, localedata.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, meta-index, sunpkcs11.jar, jaccess.jar, zipfs.jar] 
2020-11-21 18:11:02,735 [     37]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: /System/Library/Java/Extensions: [MRJToolkit.jar] 
2020-11-21 18:11:02,735 [     37]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - charsets: JNU=UTF-8 file=UTF-8 
2020-11-21 18:11:02,910 [    212]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 175 ms 
2020-11-21 18:11:02,934 [    236]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - initializing environment 
2020-11-21 18:11:02,935 [    237]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - loading shell env: /bin/bash -l -i -c '/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin/printenv.py' '/private/var/folders/zj/5qm8b1lj0m5df71f86dpmszc0000gp/T/intellij-shell-env.tmp' 
2020-11-21 18:11:03,177 [    479]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - User scale factor: 1.0 
2020-11-21 18:11:03,268 [    570]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - System scale factor: 2.0 (JRE-managed HiDPI) 
2020-11-21 18:11:11,219 [   8521]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - shell environment loaded (24 vars) 
2020-11-21 18:11:11,231 [   8533]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 
2020-11-21 18:11:13,694 [  10996]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml 
2020-11-21 18:11:13,695 [  10997]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor duplicates-detection-groovy.xml 
2020-11-21 18:11:13,785 [  11087]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - load plugin descriptors took 192 ms 
2020-11-21 18:11:13,921 [  11223]   INFO - m.intellij.ui.mac.touchbar.NST - nst library works properly, successfully created and released native touchbar object 
2020-11-21 18:11:13,984 [  11286]   INFO - .intellij.util.io.HttpRequests - Application is not initialized yet; Using default SSL configuration to connect to https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugins/list/?uuid=6083e625-a6fe-4ee3-9f31-7d3b00eb38e1&build=IC-191.8026.42 
2020-11-21 18:11:16,288 [  13590]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - CPU cores: 8; ForkJoinPool.commonPool: java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@14c412a4[Running, parallelism = 7, size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]; factory: com.intellij.concurrency.IdeaForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory@3a5a6cf2 
2020-11-21 18:11:16,507 [  13809]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml 
2020-11-21 18:11:16,508 [  13810]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor duplicates-detection-groovy.xml 
2020-11-21 18:11:16,567 [  13869]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - load plugin descriptors took 112 ms 
2020-11-21 18:11:16,699 [  14001]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 34 plugins initialized in 244 ms 
2020-11-21 18:11:16,699 [  14001]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android Support (10.3.3), Ant Support (191.8026.42), Bytecode Viewer (191.8026.42), Copyright (191.8026.42), Coverage (191.8026.42), Eclipse Integration (191.8026.42), EditorConfig (191.8026.42), Git Integration (191.8026.42), GitHub (191.8026.42), Gradle (191.8026.42), Groovy (191.8026.42), I18n for Java (191.8026.42), IDEA CORE (191.8026.42), IntelliJ Configuration Script (191.8026.42), IntelliLang (191.8026.42), JUnit (191.8026.42), Java Bytecode Decompiler (191.8026.42), Java Stream Debugger (191.8026.42), JavaFX (191.8026.42), Kotlin (1.3.21-release-IJ2019.1-3), Maven Integration (191.8026.42), Mercurial Integration (191.8026.42), Plugin DevKit (191.8026.42), Properties Support (191.8026.42), Settings Repository (191.8026.42), Smali Support (191.8026.42), Subversion (191.8026.42), Task Management (191.8026.42), Terminal (191.8026.42), TestNG-J (191.8026.42), UI Designer (191.8026.42), XPathView + XSLT Support (191.8026.42), XSLT-Debugger (191.8026.42), YAML (191.8026.42) 
2020-11-21 18:11:17,260 [  14562]   INFO - ellij.vfs.persistent.FSRecords - Marking VFS as corrupted: '/Users/mblaise/Library/Caches/IdeaIC2019.1/caches/names.dat' does not exist 
2020-11-21 18:11:17,261 [  14563]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=705 
2020-11-21 18:11:17,285 [  14587]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin/fsnotifier 
2020-11-21 18:11:17,292 [  14594]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2020-11-21 18:11:17,520 [  14822]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - local history version mismatch (was: 0, expected: 6), rebuilding... 
2020-11-21 18:11:17,520 [  14822]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - FS has been rebuild, rebuilding local history... 
2020-11-21 18:11:17,800 [  15102]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
2020-11-21 18:11:17,813 [  15115]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for interface com.intellij.openapi.extensions.PluginDescriptor 
2020-11-21 18:11:17,817 [  15119]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2020-11-21 18:11:17,889 [  15191]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
2020-11-21 18:11:17,995 [  15297]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index exts enumerated:80, number of extensions:47 
2020-11-21 18:11:18,003 [  15305]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index scheduled:7 
2020-11-21 18:11:18,034 [  15336]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - All stub exts enumerated:29, number of extensions:50 
2020-11-21 18:11:18,035 [  15337]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - stub exts update scheduled:0 
2020-11-21 18:11:18,269 [  15571]   INFO - ij.psi.stubs.StubUpdatingIndex - Following new file types will be indexed:DGM File Type,CLASS,Properties,XML,HTML,kotlin_builtins,Groovy,Kotlin,JAVA,KJSM,KNM 
2020-11-21 18:11:18,311 [  15613]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 531 ms spent to cache options in application 
2020-11-21 18:11:18,311 [  15613]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider$Activity took 531 ms 
2020-11-21 18:11:18,935 [  16237]   INFO - pl$FileIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done:931 
2020-11-21 18:11:19,271 [  16573]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done:335 
2020-11-21 18:11:20,123 [  17425]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - 83 application components initialized in 3670ms 
2020-11-21 18:11:20,136 [  17438]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 17953 ms 
2020-11-21 18:11:20,465 [  17767]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0; restored: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0 
2020-11-21 18:11:20,534 [  17836]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml 
2020-11-21 18:11:20,625 [  17927]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 247 ms spent on EDT to cache options in application 
2020-11-21 18:11:20,687 [  17989]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader took 2374 ms 
2020-11-21 18:11:21,039 [  18341]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - File /Users/mblaise/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded. 
2020-11-21 18:11:21,041 [  18343]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml 
2020-11-21 18:11:21,042 [  18344]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img2-1.xml 
2020-11-21 18:11:21,042 [  18344]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-automotive/sys-img2-1.xml 
2020-11-21 18:11:21,042 [  18344]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img2-1.xml 
2020-11-21 18:11:21,042 [  18344]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear-cn/sys-img2-1.xml 
2020-11-21 18:11:21,042 [  18344]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img2-1.xml 
2020-11-21 18:11:21,043 [  18345]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img2-1.xml 
2020-11-21 18:11:21,043 [  18345]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img2-1.xml 
2020-11-21 18:11:21,043 [  18345]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon2-1.xml 
2020-11-21 18:11:21,043 [  18345]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon2-1.xml 
2020-11-21 18:11:21,043 [  18345]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon2-1.xml 
2020-11-21 18:11:21,786 [  19088]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader took 1099 ms 
2020-11-21 18:11:21,948 [  19250]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionPreloader took 161 ms 
2020-11-21 18:11:21,950 [  19252]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.ide.actions.GotoClassPresentationUpdater took 2 ms 
2020-11-21 18:12:13,302 [  70604]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 82 ms
```

Comment: Are there any messages in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: Have you tried running the [garbage collection](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) command? It may reduce the size of the .git folder.

Comment: @y.bedrov I've attached the logs, no error message or anything

Comment: Could you please share full log. Provided part doesn't contain all information.

Comment: @y.bedrov I've added the full log

Comment: I know the base question related to IntelliJ IDEA but I think that .git folder is unnecessarily huge. That has a lot of garbage probably. Does it help if you run garbage collection on your local copy like:
```git repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250```?

Comment: Could you please try to install the latest 2020.3 Beta (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion) and check the issue with it?